# Run code on micronaut application startup

Tags: micronaut

I'm trying to find the correct way to execute some startup code which reads and uses tomcat's context.xml when running micronaut as a servlet.

I've tried creating a `@Singleton` that `implements ApplicationEventListener<ServerStartupEvent>` but that doesn't seem to get executed when my micronaut code is compiled and deployed as a war file servlet in tomcat.

Changing the `@Singleton` to a `@Context` annoation didn't help either.

The docs say that `MicronautServletInitializer` will register a new `DefaultMicronautServlet` but it doesn't look that `DefaultMicronautServlet` is a bean that you can @Replace, it just hardcodes it in there.

Is there something special needed to get Application Events to trigger?

*EDIT* this also doesn't work:

```
package com.mypackage.api;

import io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventListener;
import io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;


@Singleton
//@Context // Doesn't execute with or without
public class SystemUtilsConfig implements ApplicationEventListener<StartupEvent>
{
    @Override
    //@EventListener // doesn't execute with or without
    //@Async // doesn't execute with or without
    public void onApplicationEvent(StartupEvent startupEvent)
    {
        System.out.println("=====SystemUtilsConfig.onApplicationEvent======");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ServerStartupEvent` is used with the embedded servers, which is not the case when you deploy the WAR to the existing Tomcat instance. If you want to run the code on startup in such a case, use `ApplicationEventListener<io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent>` which will be executed after the application bootstrap is completed, no matter if the server is a running instance or an embedded one.

Comment: Thanks for looking, but still no luck.  I put the code I'm trying to use in the question.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of the problem? I created a simple demo app that uses the Tomcat servlet and builds a WAR that can be deployed to the Tomcat docker container, and the event listener for the `StartupEvent` works as expected - I can see printed lines in the console. Here's the code: https://github.com/wololock/micronaut-tomcat-demo Feel free to use this as a blueprint to provide an example that reflects your specific use case better.

Comment: Ok, yup, got it working thanks.  User error with idea.  I was building the exploded war, but  deploying the unexploded war, so none of my changes were having any effect.  Classic.